# Placing A ListView Below Other View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scroll, android-scrollview

I have been trying to Place A listview under some otherviews in Android.
For Example.

I have a Scrollview which I Place Other View Inside Including The ListView

I Want the List View to be Long as Long As 1000dp so that User can Scroll to the Listview and the Scroll the List Inside a Layout.

I have been on this for 2 days. Any Help will be highly appreciated.
This is My Code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_AllSensorhead"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSensorName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSensorNo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use **RelativeLayout**  instead of  **ScrollView**

Comment: Placing a scrollable View (the ListView) inside another scrollable View (the ScrollView) is never a good idea.

Comment: Moreover, nesting layouts is bad for performances. You don't really need 2 LinearLayouts - one inside the other one.

Comment: @AslamHossin , Using RelativeLayout does not Allow the Other Views Suchs as the PieChart to Scroll Up to Allow Only the ListView on the Screen

Comment: This is absolutely false. If you know how to use a RelativeLayout, you'll see that there's no such a limit.

Comment: @Rotwang , Please can you give me a hint ??

Comment: For instance, you can place an invisible generic View in the center of the screen and put a TextVie above it and the other one below it. We're talking about a RelativeLayout container.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scroll view to enclose all the android xml file....the defining layout should be scrollable instead of linear layout....

Comment: ,The Defining layout is a ScrollVew From The Code I Posted.

Comment: As Rotwang pointed out _"Placing a scrollable View (the ListView) inside another scrollable View (the ScrollView) is never a good idea."_

Answer (score 0):

there can be one possible solution for your problem..

As far i guess you just want to scroll whole screen that have a listview..

So, First create a different layout name like `header_listview.xml`

in that put your code apart of that listview in it..

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_AllSensorhead"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSensorName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSensorNo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Now your listview layout can be simply like

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        />
```

In your java file when fatching the instance of list..
Add two line there

```
View headerView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header_listview,null,false);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView;
```

You can get those TextViews & progressbar & chart from this headerview..like

```
TextView txt=(TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvheading);
```

from this approach the violation of scrollview with listivew wont be arrive, 
Also you dont need to give 1000dip fix height to listview..
Please tell if need more assistance..
And appreciate if it helps ..

Comment: This is how i inflate now. Can i use it with the code above. I used it but not getting it to work

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_selected_sensor, container, false);